# what is the role of event in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def key(self, event):
    directions = {Direction.left, Direction.right, Direction.up, 
Direction.down}
    if event.keysym in directions:
        self.move_player(event.keysym)
```

please explain the role of event. it is only used in this def function. Is it acting as a pointer like self.

Answer (score 0):

Be more precise.
Event is a parameter during your function call.

```
game= Game() #assuming class name game
game.key(event)
```

'event' looks like a tkinter object so add tkinter tag as well. Please do some research before asking simple questions here.